# SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager - "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" error when trying to design a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, configuration

While working in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager on a remote server today, I wanted to look at a table's columns, so I found the table, right-clicked on it and selected "Design Table".

Instead of getting the table design view, I'm greeted with a white page with the following informational message:

> Navigation to the webpage was canceled
>
> What you can try:
>
> - Refresh the page.

If I click "Refresh the page", I get another white screen with the following message:

> This program cannot display the webpage
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - You are not connected to the Internet.
> - The website is encountering problems.
> - There might be a typing error in the address.

I'm not sure who was tinkering around with the server, but I would love to know how to resolve this.

**2011/04/19 update:**  I checked, and KB961260 hasn't been installed.  The server is Windows 2003 R2, with SQL Server 2000 and Internet Explorer 8 for what it's worth.  I tried dropping security settings in IE to Low for Local and Trusted sites, which did not fix the issue.

We've also discovered that right-clicking on a table and selecting Open Table > Return All Rows gives the same error.  Designing and opening a view gives the same errors as above, but double-clicking on a view to open its properties lets us view the properties as normal.  We can also manage triggers, generate SQL scripts, etc. without issue.

Right-clicking on the first error page and checking its properties gives me this:

> res://ieframe.dll/navcancl.htm#http://%7b464ee255-fdc7-11d2-9743-00105a994f8d%7d/

Right-clicking on the second error page and checking its properties gives me this:

> res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff_webOC.htm#http://%7b464ee255-fdc7-11d2-9743-00105a994f8d%7d/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (or oddly?) a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967941) after a Windows patch to do with IE zones because of your help settings.

Comment: It says the issue is for Vista or Server 2008, and this server is still Windows 2003 R2, but I'll take a look and see if anything changed in the zones.